# Write-host two variables on same line without messing up formatting?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a code to take a `dat` file and output the data to the screen formatted. I first set all of the names to a variable and the grades. I now need to output them on the same line so they line up but when I `write-host` the first set of names it messes up the formatting of all my numbers. How can I get them to be in a straight column ?

I have tried running the code on a separate line which straightens the columns but then the numbers are a line below the names.

```
[string] $names = "{0,-10}" -f "$Name"
[string] $grades = "{0,31:f2}{1,15:f2}{2,15:f2}{3,15:f2}{4,15:f2}{5,16:f2}{6,12:f2}{7,20:f2}" -f "$Assgn1","$Assgn2","$Assgn3","$Assgn4","$Midterm","$Final","$finalgrade","$lettergrade" #Here I output the data
write-host "$names","$grades"
Jamie Zawinski                            78.8           81.0           77.3           80.0           80.0            77.0          79                   C
Adam Douglas                            86.2           69.0           77.8           81.0           87.5            88.0       81.67                   B
```

I want the grades to be lined up in a straight column without the name length affecting each line.

Comment: Can we get a sample output? And are you adverse to having them in a custom psobject?

Comment: This is for a class so I have to use things only taught in the class. I have added a sample output. That is how the output looks but for multiple lines. I would like the grades to be in a straight column.

Comment: why don't you use the same `-f` that you used in the previous two lines? you CAN use that with `Write-Host` or simply save the merged string into a 3rd $Var.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am still learning.

Comment: The width of "Name" is not enough. `$names = "{0,-20}" -f $Name`

Comment: The outcome of the format operator is a string, so there is no need to explicitly cast a variable as [string]. There is also no neeed to enclose variables in double quotes.

Comment: could you please share the dat file content? (at least several lines)

Comment: I have tested the @beastedjerky answer, he is right (proof: https://pastebin.com/X7yZTmAR)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using formatting in the Variable, could you just use multiple Write-Host statements for each data item to format the output.  By using the switch *-NoNewline* and including tabs, you could get the desired output.

Of course, this would have to be included in a loop to process each user in the list:

```
Write-Host $name -NoNewline
Write-Host "`t $assign1" -NoNewline
Write-Host "`t $assign2" -NoNewline
Write-Host "`t $assign3" -NoNewline
Write-Host "`t $assign4" -NoNewline
Write-Host "`t $Midterm" -NoNewline
Write-Host "`t $Final" -NoNewline
Write-Host "`t $finalgrade" -NoNewline
Write-Host "`t $lettergrade"
```

This will format the output with TABS between each item and all on one line.  Remember to not include the '*-NoNewline*' on the last item.